# Calculate percentage change and corresponding standard error divided by the mean

Tags: r, linear-regression

Consider the following first 20 lines of a larger dataset.

```
library(multiwayvcov)
library(lmtest)


df<-data.frame(c("A1", "A1", "A1","A1", "A2", "A2","A2","A2", "A3", "A3","A3","A3","A4","A4","A4","A4", "A5","A5","A5","A5"),
               c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0), 
               c(20160101, 20160401, 20160701,20161001,20170101, 20170401, 20170701,20171001,20170101, 20170401, 20170701,20171001,20170101, 20170401, 20170701,20171001,
                 20170101, 20170401, 20170701,20171001), 
               c(20160701,20160701,20160701,20160701, 20171001,20171001,20171001,20171001, 20170101, 20170101,20170101,20170101, 20171001, 20171001,20171001,20171001,
                 20170401, 20170401, 20170401, 20170401), c(0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,1, 1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1, 0,1,1,1), c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
colnames(df)<-c("id", "laborsupply", "date", "retirementdate", "pension.el", "gender")

df$date<-as.character(df$date)
df$retirementdate<-as.character(df$retirementdate)
df$date<-as.Date(df$date, "%Y%m%d")
df$retirementdate<-as.Date(df$retirementdate, "%Y%m%d")
```

The above dataset shows 5 individuals and their corresponding labor supply (dummy variable: 1 is active; 0 is not active) in each quarter of a particular year. Moreover, we observe in which quarter they become for the first time entitled to pension benefits (“pension.el”) and their gender. To determine how pension eligibility affects the labor supply of these individuals I run the following regression and I cluster my standard errors at the individual level. Now I want to calculate the percentage change at the moment of reaching the pension eligibility age. To do so, I first select the datapoints for which holds that "pension eligibility month" is equal to the "date" and then I calculate the mean. Lastly, I divide the coefficient I found in model1 by the mean to find the percentage difference.

```
model1<-lm(laborsupply~pension.el+gender, data = df)

#Clustered standard error  
vcov<-cluster.vcov(model1, df$id)  
coeftest(model1, vcov)

#Make subset
meandata<-subset(df, date == retirementdate)

#Calculate mean
meanls<-mean(meandata$laborsupply)

#Divide coefficients
model1$coefficients[2]/meanls
```

Now my question is whether I can calculate the standard error (clustered at the individual level) corresponding to the number I found under "Divide coefficents". Maybe I should use "cbind" to calculate the mean in my regression line of model1 , but then I don’t think it works because I only want to calculate the mean of a subset of the dataset I run the regression on. (So is it maybe just impossible to calculate a standard error when we have one coefficient being composed from a dataset that is a subset of a larger dataset?)

I would appreciate any help.